# Disable preview for vscode custom text editor extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to disable the preview mode for my custom text editor without changing the user settings (`workbench.editor.enablePreview: false`)?

Like it can be done with `vscode.window.showTextDocument()` and `vscode.workspace.TextDocumentShowOptions` were you can set `preview: false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see anything helpful in the extension api.  So here is a possible workaround.  I assume you can listen for when your custom editor is being opened - and then run this code:

```js
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.keepEditor');
```

after it is opened.  That should take it out of preview mode.  It may be the best you can do.